# Universal Image Loader: I get ConcurrentModificationException when trying to remove image from cache

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader, concurrentmodification

I need to arbitrarily replace a cached image by requesting it again from server.

I'm currently using removeFromCache as follows:

```
public void loadImage(String url, ImageView view, boolean updateCache){
    if(updateCache){
        MemoryCacheUtil.removeFromCache(url, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
    }
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, view);
}
```

The problem is sometimes it throws ConcurrentModificationException.

What's the best way to do it?

- Can I synchronize my call to remove on the Collection used internally
  in the library somehow?
- Does the library give me another way to tell
  I want to "cache miss" one image arbitrarily?

---

UIL version is 1.8.4

Stack trace:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>   at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:350)
>   at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:370) 
>   at java.util.HashSet.(HashSet.java:76) 
>   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl.LruMemoryCache.keys(LruMemoryCache.java:124)
>   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.MemoryCacheUtil.removeFromCache(MemoryCacheUtil.java:102)
>   at uk.frequency.glance.android.util.ImageLoadingManager.loadImage(ImageLoadingManager.java:120)

Comment: Which UIL version? Show full error stacktrace.

Comment: question edited @NOSTRA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known bug: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/265

Fixed in UIL **v1.8.5**.